# How to save Postgres DB entire state and restore it for dev purpose?

Tags: postgresql

I regularly explore different data models in dev, while I have one that is in prod that I should preserve.

Once I'm sure of the model I want, I have to craft a migration so that my production setup becomes this.

Unfortunatly, while I can easily git commit my data model definition and migrations, explore, then reset it as many time as I want, I don't know how to do that with postgres.

What I need is to say "my current schema, tables, functions, triggers and data are currently in a state I want to save". Then explore with it, destroy it, alter it. Then go back the way it was when I saved it.

Is there some kind of "save checkpoint" and "restore checkpoint" for the entire database ?

I know I at least 3 concepts that can be used for that : dumps, copying the data files and using the PITR, but I have no ideas how to use them efficiently for dev purpose to get something as easy and simple as a git checkout.

Using pgdumps will make me commit all stuff to git, which is not what I want. Or put things aside manually. And write all the procedure in a custom script. And wait for the dump/load. It's really far from a git checkout convenience.

Copying datafile needs the db to be restarted and takes twice the dataspace.

Using PITR seems very complicated.

Comment: Dump using `pg_dump` / `pg_dumpall` and store your script in your git repo. I believe it is the most orthodox way of doing it :-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I already do that. This is not helping for the exploration phrase where I have to reset my db every 5 minutes, and is very tedious, especially for data migrations.

Comment: @Jim Jones: that's quite long and you have to do it manually. You also have to commit data in your repo which is definitly not what I want.

Comment: You have to indeed do it manually. But with pg_dump you can dump only the object definitions, excluding the data ;-) good luck, man!

Comment: But I want the data to be saved, that's the point. I don't want it in my git repo though, it's not its place. With git I can git commit and checkout in an instance. I wish I could do that with my entire db state, from from inside the db.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *reset* your database for testing purposes and you do have a proper schema migration system in place, you can use Postgres' template system for this.

Create one database that is maintained through your schema migration and reflects the "current state".

If you want to run tests on that, create a new database using the "reference" database as the template. Note that the template can also contain data.

Then run your tests against that new database. To reset it, drop the database and re-create it from the template, e.g.:

```
create database base_template .... ;
```

Now populate `base_template` with everything you need (tables, views, functions, data, ...)

Then create a test database:

```
create database integration_test template = base_template ...;
```

Run your tests against the `integration_test` database. To reset it, simply drop and re-create it:

```
drop database integration_test;
create database integration_test template = base_template ...;
```

You just need to be careful that you run your schema migrations against the `base_template` database.

The only drawback is that you can't have any connections active to the `base_template` database when you create the clone.

Comment: I could also use bash instead of git to script the all versioning of my project. But I don't. I have a tool that does that efficiently, with one command, without copying the data entirely, without needing to write the whole process manually. I could restart my web server, rebuilt all my js / css and reload my web page with a script. But I don't, I have a toolkit that does that for me. So I'm looking for something that would allow me to dev confortably on my database without having to do the all process by hand. Which I already know how to do and is a not a good investment of resources.

Comment: @e-satis: sorry I don't get it. If you have such a tool then what is your question? (and what is that tool?)

Comment: That's an analogy. I'm comparing my code management experience with my db experience. I don't have the tool for the db. And apparently, you are all confirming it doesn't exist: you all do that stuff manually. It's very weird to me that a system that is designed literally to persist data doesn't have backed in a way to persist and restore it's own state for developpement purpose.

Comment: @e-satis: you can't apply the same concepts you use for versioning a (static) text file to a complex system like a running database server. Only needing two SQL statements that can easily be put into a single shell script `./reset_db.sh` doesn't seem much more "manual" than a single `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something like pg_dump? (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html)

You can probably create a bash script to dump your database, then read it back in once you are done experimenting (see the first link, plus ref for psql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: PG dumps supposes I commit data into the repository, which is definitly not something I want. Or I can script something to dump it separatly, and write the dumping process manually, the do it and wait for the dump / load every time. That's very dedious for dev. We have auto reload servers, instant git checkout for code, so I'm looking for something easier with db than crafting my own wheel and then wait for it to be put on the car everytime.

Comment: Committing a PG dump to a repo sounds like a horrid idea.  You should not do that.